# Adding to a pdf file the LaTeX code to generate it

Tags: pdf

I often make some `pdf` files (not so long) using `LaTeX`. I often need to later modify these files and I often can not do this because I lost the `tex` source file. You will say: "Be more careful!"....

Leaving out jokes, I am thinking of a way of creating a `pdf` file with included the `LaTeX` code for generating it, but I don't know how to do it (I do not even know if it is possible). The only thing I can imagine is to save the code in the `pdf` metadata but I don't know how much space they can occupy and a problem is that I would like also to preserve the spacing of the code (indentation and breakline).

So my questions are:

1. Do you think using metadata is a good idea? What about the size (disk space) and  the spacing of the code?
2. Have you any other idea to do it?

Comment: TeX files are very small, they are consistently smaller than their output.  Unless your document contains many images, you won't notice a size increase.  I would caution against distributing your files like this, though.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`attachfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile) package to include the source code tex file as an attachment to the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your TeX files under [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) so that you won't lose them so easily.

Comment: Addendum: TeX files under revision control *and backed up on the cloud*.

Comment: No, “the cloud” is not a backup. If you treat it as such, your data *will* be lost.